# ERROR: Cannot add 'folder-path', because it is overlapping with other DVC tracked output:

Tags: git, amazon-s3, caching, pycharm, dvc

Goal: `add` `commit` `push` all contents of `project_model/data/` to **dvcstore**.

I don't have any `.dvc` files in my project.

```
$ dvc add ./project_model/data/
ERROR: Cannot add '/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/project_model/data/images', because it is overlapping with other DVC tracked output: '/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/project_model/data'.
To include '/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/project_model/data/images' in '/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/project_model/data', run 'dvc commit project_model/data.dvc'

$ dvc commit project_model/data.dvc
ERROR: failed to commit project_model/data.dvc - 'project_model/data.dvc' does not exist
```

I've deleted contents from `.dvc/cache/` and **S3** `s3://foo/bar/dvcstore/`, with no luck.

---

```
$ dvc -V
2.10.2
```

```
$ dvc doctor
DVC version: 2.10.2 (pip)
---------------------------------
Platform: Python 3.9.12 on Linux-5.15.0-47-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
Supports:
        webhdfs (fsspec = 2022.5.0),
        http (aiohttp = 3.8.1, aiohttp-retry = 2.5.2),
        https (aiohttp = 3.8.1, aiohttp-retry = 2.5.2),
        s3 (s3fs = 2022.5.0, boto3 = 1.21.21)
Cache types: hardlink, symlink
Cache directory: ext4 on /dev/nvme0n1p5
Caches: local
Remotes: s3
Workspace directory: ext4 on /dev/nvme0n1p5
Repo: dvc, git
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I can add to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was in `dvc.yaml`.

For a few `stages`, I had cyclical dependencies, where a file-path was mentioned in both the `deps` and `outs`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have `/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/project_model/data` defined as a stage output in your `dvc.yaml`:

```yaml
stages:
  train:
  ...
  outs:
  - project_model/data
```

If that is the case, then you don't have to do an extra `dvc add` command to save this output to the remote storage. It should be taken care of by DVC automatically. Make sure that `cache: false` is not specified and that `project_model/data` is added to the `.gitignore` file though.

If you don't have `dvc.yaml`, but you are still getting this error, please try to run `dvc dag --outs` and `dvc dag` and share them with us.

Comment: This is the most likely case for others. Thanks for your answer :)